# Time dependent reaction-diffusion semigroup

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, semigroups-of-operators

I'm interested in the following linear reaction-diffusion equation

\begin{align*}
&\partial_tu(t,x) = \sigma(t)\Delta u(t,x),\\
& u(0)=u_0\in X
\end{align*}

where $X$ is a Banach space and $\sigma(t)$ is a time-dependent periodic function. I'm wondering if there are any well-posedness results and characterizations of the time-dependent semigroup when the Laplacian is multiplied by any time-dependent function. I found well-posedness theorems for contraction semigroups in Engel's *"One parameter semigroups for linear evolution equations"* and references therein. But I couldn't found anything about this type of generalization to the specific linear reaction-diffusion equation.

Comment: Set $u(t,x)=v(h(t),x)$ where $h(t)=\int_0^t \sigma (s)ds$. Then $v_t=\Delta v, v(0)=u_0$.